# Java sdk for copying to Redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

Is it possible to fire a copy command from S3 To Redshift through java jdbc connection?

Example:
  copy test from 's3://' CREDENTIALS 'aws_access_key_id=xxxxxxx;aws_secret_access_key=xxxxxxxxx'

Comment: Yes. Did you try it and got an error?

Comment: Of course it is supported. What is the issue?

Comment: how did you do that ? any links for this. Trying to do the same

Answer (score 5):

Yes try code as below

```
String dbURL = "jdbc:postgresql://x.y.us-east-1.redshift.amazonaws.com:5439/dev";
String MasterUsername = "userame";
String MasterUserPassword = "password";

           Connection conn = null;
            Statement stmt = null;
            try{
               //Dynamically load postgresql driver at runtime.
               Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");


               System.out.println("Connecting to database...");
               Properties props = new Properties();


               props.setProperty("user", MasterUsername);
               props.setProperty("password", MasterUserPassword);
               conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL, props);
               stmt = conn.createStatement();
               String sql="copy test from 's3://' CREDENTIALS     'aws_access_key_id=xxxxxxx;aws_secret_access_key=xxxxxxxxx'"
                int j = stmt.executeUpdate(sql);

                stmt.close();
               conn.close();
            }catch(Exception ex){
               //For convenience, handle all errors here.
               ex.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Sandesh's answer works perfectly fine, but it uses PostgreSql driver. AWS Provides Redshift driver, which is better than PostgreSql driver.
Rest of things would remain same. I hope this information may help others.

1)JDBC Driver will change from `org.postgresql.Driver` to  `com.amazon.redshift.jdbcXX.Driver`, where XX is the version of Redshift driver. e.g. `42`.

2)Jdbc url will change from `postgreSQL` to `redshift`.

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.Properties;

public class RedShiftJDBC {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Connection conn = null;
        Statement statement = null;
        try {
            //Make sure to choose appropriate Redshift Jdbc driver and its jar in classpath
            Class.forName("com.amazon.redshift.jdbc42.Driver");
            Properties props = new Properties();
            props.setProperty("user", "username***");
            props.setProperty("password", "password****");

            System.out.println("\n\nconnecting to database...\n\n");
            //In case you are using postgreSQL jdbc driver.

            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:redshift://********url-to-redshift.redshift.amazonaws.com:5439/example-database", props);

            System.out.println("\n\nConnection made!\n\n");

            statement = conn.createStatement();

            String command = "COPY my_table from 's3://path/to/csv/example.csv' CREDENTIALS 'aws_access_key_id=******;aws_secret_access_key=********' CSV DELIMITER ',' ignoreheader 1";

            System.out.println("\n\nExecuting...\n\n");

            statement.executeUpdate(command);
            //you must need to commit, if you realy want to have data copied.
            conn.commit();
            System.out.println("\n\nThats all copy using simple JDBC.\n\n");
            statement.close();
            conn.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```