# Can Spring Batch work with Amazon Redshift?

Tags: spring-batch, amazon-redshift

I'm trying to use Spring Batch (4.0.1.RELEASE) working with Amazon Redshift. I got through the first major problem with Redshift's lack of support for sequences [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20789731/using-redshfit-as-spring-batch-job-repository-and-alternatives-to-sequence-in-re).

However, now I've run into this when I try to run a job:

```
10:57:07.122 ERROR [http-nio-8080-exec-4 ] [JobLaunchingService] [] Could not start job [demoJob]
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [INSERT INTO BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION_CONTEXT (SHORT_CONTEXT, SERIALIZED_CONTEXT, JOB_EXECUTION_ID) VALUES(?, ?, ?)[Amazon][JDBC](10220) Driver does not support this optional feature.; nested exception is java.sql.SQLFeatureNotSupportedException: [Amazon][JDBC](10220) Driver does not support this optional feature.
```

This is with the Redshift 1.2.16.1027 JDBC Driver.

Is it even possible to use Redshift as the batch database? Any suggestions on how to get around this?

Comment: what is a batch database? anyway i guess not, redshift <> postgres. there are plenty of ETL platforms compatible with redshift, why not use one of those.

Comment: The "batch" database is where Spring Batch stores its control tables. I'm using it because I already have a dozen jobs written in Spring Batch, I just want to change from a MySQL target database to Redshift.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about you use case, if it is limitation or constrained that you need to have `Spring` batch only. Also, the `jdbc` driver, says ***It doesn't support the batch.***, then I believe there is no way around to make it work.
As a recommended approach and best practice, in `Redshift` instead of `insert statement`, `COPY` command should be used. Though, you could call the `copy` command using plain `JDBC` could be good idea.

You could take a look at one my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18465313/java-sdk-for-copying-to-redshift/51908509#51908509), I have provided earlier.
I'm just copy/pasting it make it handy.

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.Properties;

public class RedShiftJDBC {
public static void main(String[] args) {

Connection conn = null;
Statement statement = null;
try {
//Make sure to choose appropriate Redshift Jdbc driver and its jar in classpath
Class.forName("com.amazon.redshift.jdbc42.Driver");
Properties props = new Properties();
props.setProperty("user", "username***");
props.setProperty("password", "password****");

System.out.println("\n\nconnecting to database...\n\n");
//In case you are using postgreSQL jdbc driver.

conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:redshift://********url-to-redshift.redshift.amazonaws.com:5439/example-database", props);

System.out.println("\n\nConnection made!\n\n");

statement = conn.createStatement();

String command = "COPY my_table from 's3://path/to/csv/example.csv' CREDENTIALS 'aws_access_key_id=******;aws_secret_access_key=********' CSV DELIMITER ',' ignoreheader 1";

System.out.println("\n\nExecuting...\n\n");

statement.executeUpdate(command);
//you must need to commit, if you realy want to have data copied.
conn.commit();
System.out.println("\n\nThats all copy using simple JDBC.\n\n");
statement.close();
conn.close();
 } catch (Exception ex) {    ex.printStackTrace();   }  } }
```

I hope this gives you some idea. If you have specific question add a comment, I should be able to refocus the answer.

Answer (score 0):

In order to make this work, I had to define a separate MySQL database for the Spring Batch "control" tables.  That was the default (`@Primary`) database in the Batch application. The `ItemWriter`s are fed with a different `DataSource`, the one that was pointed at Redshift.

So now I've got a `DataSource` for the Batch tables, one for my source db, and one for the target db.  That seems to work, but I'm only using the standard `DataSourceTransactionManager` so it's not clear at all to me what the transactional boundaries are, if a step fails whether the databases are rolled back the same way. But I am NOT going to use XA!!

Comment: if you are generating and submitting inserts - you may find performance issues. you may need to consider staging the data to s3 then issuing copy command on redshift.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon Redshift is not a supported database for Spring Batch. The supported databases are listed here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/tree/master/spring-batch-core/src/main/resources/org/springframework/batch/core.